# ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool- Python Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping using python and am having some initial trouble getting started. I have installed all the right imnports but still am getting this errors:

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='econpy.pythonanywhere.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /ex/001.html (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000000000C5A7630>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))

I checked my proxy settings in google chrome and the 'Use HTTP 1.1 through proxy connections' was checked. Any ideas ?

Here is the code i am trying just to get something to work:
from lxml import html
import requests

```
page = requests.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will create a list of buyers:
buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
#This will create a list of prices
prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')

print 'Buyers: ', buyers
print 'Prices: ', prices
```

Comment: where are you running this code from? why do you think the proxy settings is an issue here?

Comment: @conrad I am running the code spyder , i have also tried running it straight through the command line with no luck.  From the error message i was assuming this was an issue with my internet settings rather than python but I really have no idea. Any recommendations would help!

Comment: it does sound like an internet connectivity issue. Are you even able to connect to http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html from the browser?